# Process grouping in linux

Tags: linux, service, process, systemd, cgroups

I have recently seen some screencasts about process management with `systemd` and `cgroups` and I am a little confused about the distinction among:

a) **services**: in the typical linux terminology, where a service can comprise more than one process; how are processes belonging to the same service grouped? under what convention?

b) **process groups**: the typical grouping of process according to the POSIX standard

c) **slices**: the concept used by `systemd` to group services (and scopes) for resource allocation/limitation (among others)

Answer (score 1):

You can consider slices à the "cgroups the systemd way". By default each services has it's own slice (use `systemd-cgls` to print them out) and inside a unit file you can custom ressources allowed to this particular unit, for example if i print status of an nginx instance :

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2015-01-27 19:41:23 EST; 22h ago
 Main PID: 495 (nginx)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─495 nginx: master process /usr/bin/nginx -g pid /run/nginx.pid; error_log stderr;
           └─496 nginx: worker process
```

You can see the related Cgroup or "slice" use by this service.

in order to custom ressource management, you have to add something like

```
[Slice]
CPUShares=512
MemoryLimit=2G
```

Inside unit fail, then `systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart nginx`

You can also combine slices to create an "array of services" (ask if you want to know more about this) that will share a defined ressources limit. This is a .slice unit https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.slice.html. Basically you create a .slice unit then start + enable it and tell other service to use this slice inside the "slice" part of the service unit.

Also, more information about control ressources tunning : https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html

Edit :

Adding those ressources constraints will limit ressources used by your nginx service and keep your other services safe if nignx goes crazy because of a DDOS or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to clarify as it seems you are mixing different terminology.

**Process Groups**
This terminology is not used within cgroups, you might be referring to 'control group' which basically is the abbreviation for cgroup. I noticed several websites wrongfully use process groups when they actually mean control groups.

Cgroups uses the following terminology: Slices, Scopes, Services

**Slices**
These are unit types for creating the cgroup hierarchy for resource management. 
By default there are three slices:

- system (by default contains boot process)
- User (by default contains user sessions)
- machine (default created but not used and left for virtual enviroments to use)

**Scope**
Organizational unit that groups a daemon’s worker processes. You can look at it as 'slices within a slice'.

**Services**
Process or group of processes controlled by systemd. Basically the process that you control(stop/start/status) via systemctl.